# Manually specify view and model matrices in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Is there any way to manually specify view and model matrices?

I know Three.js is not supposed to be used in this way, but I am currently developing some educational materials to teach a typical computer graphics pipeline and would like to explicitly supply `model/view/projection` matrices to a shader. While I understood which matrices are `model/view/projection` matrices in Three.js from [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1188), I haven't been able to find a good way to manually control them.

So far, I was able to specify the projection matrix by using `camera.projectionMatrix.makePerspective()` and the model matrix by using `applyMatrix()`. Actually, `applyMatrix()` is not ideal from the educational point of view because it internally decomposes the matrix to position, quaternion and scale and probably reconstructs the model matrix from those values and supply it to a shader.

One possible solution is to use `ShaderMaterial()` and specify all of the three matrices as uniforms. However, I may want to avoid it because they are also passed to a shader implicitly and the name "material" might confuse students.

Does anybody have suggestions to do this kind of stuff in Three.js?

Comment: If naming is the only issue preventing you from using `THREE.ShaderMaterial` or `THREE.RawShaderMaterial`, you can always alias the object: `THREE.CustomShader = THREE.ShaderMaterial;`, `var myShader = new THREE.CustomShader();`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That's actually a great idea.

Comment: `RawShaderMaterial` should not inject anything for you.

Comment: I would disagree with the "material" being confusing though. Within the api, what you are using is a "material" since it's not just GLSL, but also properties that get interpreted by the renderer when making draw calls. Your  `ShaderMaterial` would consist of two different shaders. But together, they make a material in three.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I may want to avoid it because they are also passed to a shader implicitly and the name "material" might confuse students.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach. A `Material` in three.js should indeed be more than a shader. It consists of two shaders, but other stuff as well. For example if you set `myMaterial.transparent = true;` you will trigger a completely different flow of `WebGLRenderer` which in turn sets up different WebGL calls. Setting the blending mode for example is not what a shader does.

It would probably be worth explaining this abstraction, rather than renaming it.

> ...matrices in Three.js from this issue, I haven't been able to find a good way to manually control them.

With `RawShaderMaterial` you should be able to write the whole shader from scratch.

```
uniform mat4 uMyProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMyModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMyViewMatrix;
uniform mat5 uMyModelViewMatrix;

attribute vec3 aMyPosition;

void main(){

  gl_Position = uMyProjectionMatrix * uMyViewMatrix * uMyModelMatrix * vec4( aMyPositon , 1.);

}
```

It is entirely up to you to define what those are. Is the projection matrix orthographic or not for example.

With `ShaderMaterial` you get these automagically:

```
void main(){

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4( position , 1. );

}
```

`projectionMatrix` and `viewMatrix` are derived from the camera's properties, as you can see in the link *(btw i've no idea why that's not in the documentation, i found myself referring to that particular issue a bunch of times :) )*.

Both of these can be modified. Automagically if you do

```
myCamera.far = newFar;
myCamera.fov = newFov;
myCamera.updateProjectionMatrix(); //this will be the new projectionMatrix in GLSL
```

but, nothing should be preventing you from doing

```
myCamera.projectionMatrix.array[3] = mySkewLogic;
```

Same applies to `modelMatrix`:

```
myObject.position.x = newX;
myObject.updateMatrixWorld();
//or
myObject.matrixWorld.array[3] = someXTranslationLogic;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It is very helpful.

I think I would go for the alias of `RawShaderMaterial()`.